# Run code when application is installed

Tags: android, google-play

I need to know if it is possible to execute code when an application is installed. I've seen that there is a way to run when it starts only for the first time. But I need to run a code when it installs.

I have an application that we develop and we go to another store (IBM Store), when an application is downloaded from the Play Store creates an icon in the "desktop" of the phone. From the IBM Store this does not happen, I had to do it from the code

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Movistar Click");
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);

addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.icon));
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

However this code is executed when the application opens, not when it is installed.

> Is there any way to run code when the application is installed?

Comment: nope that's not possible

Comment: @Max Is there any way to create the shortcut icon otherwise?

Comment: i believe if you have a proper drawable its should create an icon... maybe it's a specifics of IBM store. try to download any other app from IBM store and check for its icon

Comment: Unfortunately it does not do it from the store ibm :(

Comment: It doesn't do it from any store-  it will create the icons on the apps drawer, not on the launcher screen.  This is by design-  cluttering up a user's launcher is a poor user experience.  Its a giant pain in the neck on Windows that everyone decided not to replicate in the mobile world.  If the user wants a launcher icon, he can make it for himself.  This is especially important given the low amount of physical space in mobile.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I find it excellent and very useful to defend the argument of not doing it. @GabeSechan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to know if it is possible to execute code when an application is installed.

No, sorry.

> But I need to run a code when it installs

So do malware authors.

> when an application is downloaded from the Play Store creates an icon in the "desktop" of the phone

That is up to the user and the home screen implementation, as well as potentially the app distribution channel. So, for example, I have this turned off — both at the Play Store and at my home screen — because IMHO it is a really stupid "feature".

> I had to do it from the code

There is no requirement for every home screen implementation to support this broadcast. Also note that this is replaced outright on Android 8.0 with a different system.